# Different performance in PostgreSQL with the samae query

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I tried to run two PostreSQL query but the performace result is differed very much.

First query:

`SELECT "timestamp", example_id FROM public.example where example_id = 7 order by "timestamp"  desc limit 1;`

Result:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                               |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Limit  (cost=388631.01..388631.02 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=1190.067..1197.096 rows=1 loops=1)                                       |
  ->  Sort  (cost=388631.01..388631.02 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=1177.076..1184.104 rows=1 loops=1)                                  |
        Sort Key: "timestamp" DESC                                                                                                       |
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB                                                                                        |
        ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..388631.00 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=189.743..1182.464 rows=1827 loops=1)                          |
              Workers Planned: 4                                                                                                         |
              Workers Launched: 4                                                                                                        |
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on exmaple  (cost=0.00..387630.90 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=112.112..1097.750 rows=365 loops=5)|
                    Filter: (example_id = 7)                                                                                              |
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 7367550                                                                                      |
Planning Time: 0.224 ms                                                                                                                  |
JIT:                                                                                                                                     |
  Functions: 21                                                                                                                          |
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true                                                          |
  Timing: Generation 7.577 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 6.485 ms, Emission 59.015 ms, Total 73.077 ms                             |
Execution Time: 1199.038 ms                                                                                                              |
```

First query:

`SELECT "timestamp", example_id FROM public.example where example_id = 1 order by "timestamp"  desc limit 1;`

Result:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Limit  (cost=0.56..0.61 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=0.090..0.096 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                  |
  ->  Index Scan using example_timestamp_idx on exmaple  (cost=0.56..810781.97 rows=17351949 width=22) (actual time=0.085..0.087 rows=1 loops=1)|
        Index Cond: (example_id = 1)                                                                                                                 |
Planning Time: 0.194 ms                                                                                                                             |
Execution Time: 0.141 ms                                                                                                                            |
```

DLL:

```
CREATE TABLE public.example (
    "timestamp" timestamp(6) NOT NULL,
    sv varchar NOT NULL,
    example_id int2 NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    CONSTRAINT example_pk PRIMARY KEY ("timestamp", example_id, sv),
    CONSTRAINT example_fk FOREIGN KEY (example_id) REFERENCES public.example2(id)
);
CREATE INDEX example_timestamp_idx ON public.example USING btree ("timestamp" DESC, example_id);

CREATE TABLE public.example2 (
    id smallserial NOT NULL,
    name varchar NULL,
    CONSTRAINT example2_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Why the first query is slower? With example_id = 7 only a few rows exist.

**EDITED**:

- I added DLL and examplain plan
- I inserted the id(7) to example2 table later then the id(1)

I tried to run VACUM ANALYSE and using EXPLAIN funtions to get the the same performace.

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) for this statement? Complete and in plain text. Could you also share the DDL for the tables and indexes involved? (the entire plan, not just one line of the plan)

Comment: You use `example_id` in the description, but the explain plan suggests the actual field is `server_id`. In any case, do you have a composite index on the two fields beginning with the id one? Something like `(example_id, timestamp DESC)`

Comment: @user20042973 Sorry I copied the wrong  explain plan. I edited my question.

Comment: This is a typical no index vs index comparison.

Comment: @FrankHeikens It added the DLL of my tables, where you can see that I use indexes. I dont't understand why the first query use index and the second not. The only difference of the two query is the different id number.

Comment: I'm a bit lost: You show us a query that is slow, then a query that is fast. And you claim that the second one (!)  is slow, while just showed us the opposite. You show us a query plan for table exmaple, and you show us a query for table example. Indexes exmaple_timestamp_idx and example_timestamp_idx are also different. I thinks you have to review first your code, then your query plans and then update this question to get a question that matches the information you give us. And is autovacuum active? And when did it run?

Comment: @FrankHeikens Yes, you right, the first query is the slower as you can see in the execution time. I edited my question. The autovacuum is active and and I have ran the VACUUM FULL command.

Comment: As @user20042973 mentions, are you sure you haven't created the index using `(example_id, "timestamp" DESC)` instead of `("timestamp" DESC, example_id)` in your second example?

Comment: Yes, @user20042973 is right. Sorry, I missed this answer.